# How to write a flow where the Oracle service signs transactions in parallel with Peers in Corda

Tags: corda

From the docs, I understand that there is a way to allow for parallel signing between peers and Oracle but don't see how this works functionally in the given flow on the Corda docs:

> 1. *The creator of the transaction that depends on the interest rate
>      asks for the current rate. They can abort at this point if they want
>      to.*
> 2. *They insert a command with that rate and the time it was
>      obtained into the transaction.*
> 3. *They then send it to the oracle for
>      signing, along with everyone else, potentially in parallel. The
>      oracle checks that the command has the correct data for the asserted
>      time, and signs if so.*

Was the command not provided by the Oracle in the first place thus signing the transaction in step one? I understand that the aim here is to avoid first-sign from the Oracle but how is the above flow facilitating this? How can the rate be obtained if not via the Oracle, and would the Oracle not have to sign on that first provision? Is this a case where the Oracle attests twice; once when providing the fact to the requestor and twice when the requestor re-inserts the fact as a command to be validated by both the Oracle and the remaining peers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Corda 3, there is no way to request signatures in parallel. This feature will likely be added in a future release. For now, you have to request the signatures in a specific order.

The oracle does not sign the command it provides. Instead:

- The creator of the transaction receives the command from the oracle and includes it in the transaction
- Once the transaction is fully built, the creator of the transaction sends the transaction back to the oracle
- The oracle decides whether to sign:

  - If the data in the command is correct, the oracle should sign the entire transaction
  - If the data in the command is incorrect, the oracle should refuse to sign

This approach prevents signed oracle data from being reused across transactions. Since each transaction has a unique hash, a signature needs to be requested for each individual use of the oracle data, allowing the oracle to charge per-use and have a viable business model.